# Next.js 14 'Wrong mime type' error after deploying on IIS

Tags: next.js, nextjs-rewrites

I have a very simple Next.js app that uses app router and i18n and everything works good locally, but as soon as I deploy it to IIS, I get warnings in console for both js and css files: The script from “https://some-domain.eu/_next/static/chunks/app/%5Blng%5D/page-ff2a904e6ac40466.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type. I've been stuck on this problem for 2 days now without a solution in sight. Please, if anyone knows how to fix this, let me know, all advices are much appreciated!

here is my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
      <add name="StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="StaticContent" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/public/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/public{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
     <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <iisnode node_env="production" />

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and my server.js code

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');
const { NextResponse } = require('next/server');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const acceptLanguage =  require("accept-language");

// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const fallbackLng = "en";
const languages = [fallbackLng, "hr"];
acceptLanguage.languages(languages);


function getLocale(request) {
    const acceptLanguageHeader = request.headers.get("Accept-Language");
  
    if (!acceptLanguageHeader) {
      return fallbackLng;
    }
  
    // Split the Accept-Language header into an array of language tags
    const acceptedLangs = acceptLanguageHeader
      .split(",")
      .map((language) => language.trim().split(";")[0]);

  
    // Find the best match between the supported locales and the client's preferred languages
    const locale = acceptedLangs.find((lang) => languages.includes(lang)) || fallbackLng;
  
    return locale;
  }

  const config = {
    // matcher: '/:lng*'
    matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)"],
  };
  app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(async (req, res) => {

        // Emergent bug in Next.js: doesn't deal wll with brackets in 
        // URL when iisnode or other reverse proxy is in the middle.
        // See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54325
        let reqUrl = req.url
            .replace(/\[/g, '%5B')
            .replace(/\]/g, '%5D');
            console.log(`>>> ` + reqUrl);

        try { 
          if (req.nextUrl.startsWith("/_next") || req.nextUrl.startsWith("/assets/")) {
            return NextResponse.next();
          } else {
            const { pathname, origin } = req.nextUrl
            const pathnameHasLocale = languages.some(
              (locale) => req.nextUrl.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || req.nextUrl === `/${locale}`
            )
      
            if (!pathnameHasLocale) {
              // get locale
              const locale = getLocale(req)
        
              //check if user is on root and redirect to default locale
              if (pathname === '/') {
                const redirectPath = `${origin}/${locale}`;
                return NextResponse.redirect(redirectPath);
              } else {
                if (config.matcher.some((pattern) => new RegExp(pattern).test(pathname))) {
                  return;
                }           
                console.log("redirect: ", `${origin}/${locale}${pathname}`);
                return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/${locale}${pathname}`);
              }
            
            }
          }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred handling', reqUrl, err);
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
              // Handle 404 errors
              return app.render(req, res, '/404', {
                statusCode: 404,
                title: 'Page Not Found',
              });
            } else {
              // Handle other errors (500)
              return app.render(req, res, '/500', {
                statusCode: 500,
                title: 'Internal Server Error',
              });
            }
        }
    })
    .listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
    });
  });
```

I've tried to change web.config rules with adding mimeMap and setting mimeType to text/css for css and text/javascript for js, but that resulted in 500 error